# Proof-finding: Power iteration and complexity of the Rayleigh quotient

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm searching for a proof for this theorem:

\begin{align}
|\lambda^{(k)}-\lambda_1| = \mathcal{O}\Big(\Big|\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}\Big|^{2k}\Big)
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
\lambda^{(k)} : = \frac{(x^k)^TAx^k}{(x^k)^Tx^k}
\end{align}

is the Rayleigh quotient iteration and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $A=A^T$, $|\lambda_1|\geq ... \geq |\lambda_n|$ eigenvalues of A.

I found one in a german book by Hanke-Bourgeois (Theorem 25.3) but it's very technical. Does any of you know where to find a simple proof for that?

Thank you!

Comment: You can find a simple proof in Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan: http://books.google.fr/books?id=X5YfsuCWpxMC&lpg=PP1&dq=golub%20van%20loan&hl=cs&pg=PA451#v=onepage&q=golub%20van%20loan&f=false If you don't care about the constant factor, you just look on the last two lines of the proof of Theorem 8.2.1.